# How can I change the dropdown option into different form on product page?

Tags: php, magento, product

Iam a newbie in magento and i got something very tricky on product page.
I have to hide the dropdown option from here and show all the attributes values in a single line like

[Size : Small Medium Large]

[Color : Red Green Pink]

but the color will only show after selecting the size like in default magento dropdown.
I am able to get all the attribute according to the product id but how can i get the color attribute according to the size attribute for a particular product, and then pass that values to the cart page after clicking on the add to cart button.

I have really stuck in this task can someone help me please..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
$sizeStr = '';
$colorStr = '';
$attrs = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
foreach($attrs as $attr) {
    if(0 == strcmp("size", $attr['attribute_code'])) {
        $sizeStr .= $attr['values']." "; //get size
    }else if(0 == strcmp("color", $attr['attribute_code'])) {
        $colorStr .= $attr['values']." "; // get color
    }
}
```

Comment: it will only show the attributes of size and color. that thing i have already done. i want to show the color after selecting the size attribute.
like i have 3 color in small size and 5 in medium size. how can i do that.
Thanks